# Regex for lines containing arrows

Tags: regex

On my blog I am using a plugin called Search Regex.

At the end of each Post, I delineate the lineage of the person the Post is about.

What is the regular expression please that would

Replace:

```
Joe Smith --> John Smith --> Bill Smith
```

With:

```
(div tag here)Joe Smith --> John Smith --> Bill Smith(closing div tag here)
```

Basically **any** line that contains a **dash dash greater than sign** I want the line to begin with this div tag and end with the closing div tag.

What is the regular expression that would identify any line with a dash dash greater than sign and then insert the above div tags please?

Comment: What language are you using this in?

Comment: What flavor of regex does the plugin use? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the regular expression `/.*-->.*/` with the value `<div>$0</div>`, where `$0` is a placeholder for the matched string (the exact syntax may vary depending on what language you are using).

Note that `.` does not match a new line by default.